# ($X^{T}AX=0,\;\;\forall X$) iff $A$ is a skew symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$X$ is a column vector and $A$ is a square Matrix.

$\leftarrow$

$X^{T}AX=X^{T}A^{T}X=X^{T}(-A)X \implies X^{T}AX =0$

$\rightarrow$

I'm stuck here I tried doing the above backwards but I don't think I can say that 
$X^{T}A^{T}X=X^{T}(-A)X \implies A^{T}=-A$, can I ?

any help or hints will be appreciated. thanks !

Comment: $X^{T}A^{T}X=X^{T}(-A)X$ for a fixed, arbitrary (or even cleverly chosen) $X$ does not imply that $A$ is skew symmetric. The trick here is that we assume that $X^{T}A^{T}X=X^{T}(-A)X$ is true for _all_ $X$ simultaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a first step we prove this for the case $n=2$ where $X\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ be given such that $X^TAX=0$ for all $X$.
Then chosing $X=(1,0)$ and $X=(0,1)$ yields that the diagonal of $A$ has to be zero.
So, we assume
$$
 A= 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & a \\ b & 0
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Chosing $X=(1,1)$ yields $X^T AX = a+b$, thus $a=-b$, thus $A=-A^T$.

This easily extends to higher dimensions, by proving the same for all $2\times 2$ sub-matrices

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 a_{ii} & a_{ij} \\ a_{ji} & a_{jj}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

with $1\leq i< j\leq n$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $x^TAx=0$ for all $x$, and define $B=A+A^T$. Then it is clear that:

- $B$ is symmetric
- $x^TBx=0$ for all $x$

As a symmetric matrix, $B$ has a complete set of orthonormal eigenvectors $v_i$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, such that $Bv_i = \lambda_i v_i$, and any $x$ can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^n \langle x,v_i \rangle v_i$.

Then:

$$0 = x^TBx = x^TB\sum_{i=1}^n \langle x,v_i \rangle v_i = x^T\sum_{i=1}^n \langle x,v_i \rangle \lambda_i v_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle x,v_i \rangle^2 \lambda_i $$

Taking $x=v_j$ shows that $\lambda_j=0$ for all $j$, i.e. $B \equiv 0$.

It thus follows that $A+A^T=0$, and hence that $A$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: .. at the same time  similar idea ..

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** What does $X^TAX=0$ mean when $X$ is a standard basis vector? And if $X$ is the sum of two distinct standard basis vectors?

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $A$ can be presented as the sum of its symmetric and skew-symmetric part $A=A_{sym}+A_{sk}$.

From this and $X^TA X=0 $ we have $X^TA_{sym}X=-X^TA_{sk}x$.

It was proved previously (in OP)  that for  $A_{sk}$ for all vectors $X$ we have $x^TA_{sk}x=0$,
so we should have  **for all** vectors $X$ also $X^TA_{sym}X=0$.

But this is not true for all vectors $X$ if $A_{sym}$ is non-zero matrix.

At least it is not true for eigenvectors of $A_{sym}$ with non-zero eigenvalue - in this case $X^TA_{sym}X=X^T\lambda{X}=\lambda(X^TX)$ is not equal zero because $(X^TX= \Vert X \Vert ^2)$ is not zero  and $\lambda$ is not zero.

So we can infer that symmetrical part of $A$ in these conditions must be zero matrix.